# Is there a way to store images in Azure or AWS without hosting the application on their platforms?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, azure, backend

I am currently developing a full-stack web application for the first time. It is a store that needs to give users the ability to upload "books", edit, delete, and manage them. As of now, I have a React front-end, that calls an Express API using Axios that queries a MySQL database.  This currently can manage the product details, titles, and simple labels and relations.

However, I now need to store images and .json files dynamically as well. So, I have researched and need to use Azure Storage to store these images and allow access to them by the end-user. I have researched it and the client would like to use Azure storage as well.

I have gotten quite overwhelmed looking into the Azure documentation for Javascript image uploading, and every "tutorial" starts with create a web application, storage account, and app service.

All I would like to do is store images from the user in Azure storage, so that when I eventually deploy the website, the data is available to be accessed and then my front end or API can call Azure to get the images for the user. I apologize if the question is confusing or vague, I am really just overwhelmed by Azure's documentation and it seems like such a simple and common problem.  Any guidance or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's quite possible. You simply create an Azure Storage account and upload your files as blobs via that account. Then they will be available publicly on the Internet, and your web application can reference them from wherever it is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible as I believe it is quite a common practice to have a Content Delivery Network to deliver the images. I am not very familiar with Azure but I am with AWS and I can tell you that you can use an [AWS S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store the images and JSON. It comes with many different configuration options to allow content to be protected or open to the general internet.